# Tikz: Draw Rectangle around a rotated non-regular shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=-{30}]
\draw (0,0)--(0,4)--(4,4)--(4,2)--(6,2)--(6,0)--(4,0)--(4,-2)--(2,-2)--(2,0)--cycle;
\draw (2, 0)--++(2,0);
\draw (0, 2)--++(4,0);
\draw (2,4)--++(0,-4);
\draw (4,2)--++(0,-2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. What is the proper way to draw a rectangle around this shape so that
   it touches far left, right, top, bottom points?
2. I have a feeling that I haven't constructed the non-regular shape in
   a systematic manner. How could I do it better?
3. [**Addendum upon Torbjørn's initial answer**] How can I fill the
   bounding box, but exclude the shape inside? And how can I, say, draw
   a line from the shape to the bounding box.)

Comment: `\draw (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,0) rectangle ++(2,2)
(0,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (4,-2) rectangle ++(2,2)
(2,-4) rectangle ++(2,2);` also draws the shape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An easy way is to use the `fit` library along with a `local bounding box`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=-{30},local bounding box=a]
\draw (0,0)--(0,4)--(4,4)--(4,2)--(6,2)--(6,0)--(4,0)--(4,-2)--(2,-2)--(2,0)--cycle;
\draw (2, 0)--++(2,0);
\draw (0, 2)--++(4,0);
\draw (2,4)--++(0,-4);
\draw (4,2)--++(0,-2);
\end{scope}
\node [fit=(a),inner sep=0pt,draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or, given the `local bounding box`, use a `rectangle` path:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=-{30},local bounding box=a]
\draw (0,0) |- (4,4) |- (6,2) |- (4,0) |- (2,-2) |- cycle;
\draw (4, 0) -| (2,4)
      (0,2) -| (4,0);
\end{scope}
\draw (a.south west) rectangle (a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(This shows the use of `-|`/`|-` paths to cut the number of coordinates in half.)

If drawing the same lines more than once isn't a problem, you could use a loop like this to draw the shape:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=-{30},local bounding box=a]
\foreach \x/\y in {1/0,0/1,1/1,2/1,0/2,1/2} % list of rectangle centers
   \draw (\x-0.5, \y-0.5) rectangle ++(1,1);
\end{scope}
\draw (a.south west) rectangle (a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Addendum

Perhaps the easiest way to achieve your additional requirements is to use nodes to make the squares, and a `fit` node to make the rectangle. By filling the nodes with white, and using `on background layer` to fill the `fit` node with some other colour, you get the appearance you're asking for. If you actually want to fill only the area between shape and rectangle you need to use `\clip` in a `scope`, and I'd actually suggest asking a new question.

Because everything is a node, drawing lines between inner squares and outer rectangle is easy, just use the node anchors as coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=-{30},local bounding box=a]
\foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {1/0,0/1,1/1,2/1,0/2,1/2} % list of rectangle centers
   \node [transform shape, % allow for rotation
          draw, % draw outline
          fill=white, % fill with white
          minimum size=1cm, % set size
          name=n-\i,
          %label=center:n-\i % if you want to see the names of the nodes, uncomment this
          ] at (\x-0.5, \y-0.5) {};
\end{scope}
\scoped[on background layer] % the following path is on the background layer
  \node [draw=black, fill=blue!10, fit=(a), inner sep=0.2pt, name=frame] {};


\draw [-latex] (frame.280) to[bend right] (n-1);
\draw (frame.east) -- (n-3.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be the way to fill the rectangle but not the shape inside?

Comment: @blackened Depends a bit on what you mean exactly. Do you want to fill the area inside the rectangle, but outside the shape, or do you want to fill the entire rectangle, but have the shape on top of the filling?

Comment: I want to fill the rectangle but exclude the shape inside. (Though, what I really want to understand is how the mechanism works.)

Comment: In fact, I have just realized that I also need to, say, draw a line from the shape inside to the rectangle itself? How can I do that? Shall I edit the question accordingly?

Comment: @blackened The best thing would be if you had realized that before posting the question in the first place, so you could have added all the requirements at once. As I did think of a fairly easy way of doing all that, I edited my answer though.

Comment: You are right (sorry for that). (The problem was that I thought I could deal with those further problems by myself once I know how to draw the bounding rectangle.) I will edit the question and if you wish delete my comments so that people can follow more easily.