# Tikz: Draw to the bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf

[Following my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434964/48787) (when I asked that one I thought the rest would be relatively easier):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [plotmark/.style = {%
    solid,
    fill=red,
    circle,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    minimum size = 4pt}]

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-{30},local bounding box=a]
    \draw (0,0) |- (4,4) |- (6,2) |- (4,0) |- (2,-2) |- cycle;
    \draw (4, 0) -| (2,4)
          (0,2) -| (4,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,-2);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,4);
    \node[plotmark] at (A){};
    \node[plotmark] at (B){};
    \end{scope}
    \draw (a.south west) rectangle (a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. What are my options to fill the bounding box but exclude the inner shape? (Torbjørn T. [provided an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434965/48787) with `on background layer` but advised to ask it as a separate question.) How can I do it with `clip` and `scope`?
2. How can I draw a line which passes through the two red points and intersects with the bounding box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Without backgrounds and clip.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [plotmark/.style = {%
    solid,
    fill=red,
    circle,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    minimum size = 4pt}]

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-{30},local bounding box=a]
    \draw[fill=gray,even odd rule] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,0) rectangle ++(2,2) (0,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (4,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,-4) rectangle ++(2,2)
     (a.north west) -- (a.north east) -- (a.south east) -- (a.south west)
     --(a.north west);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,-4);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \node[plotmark] at (A){};
    \node[plotmark] at (B){};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[name path global=bbox] (a.south west) rectangle 
    (a.north east);
    \path[overlay,name path=line] let \p1=(A),\p2=(B),\p3=(a.south),\p4=(a.north),\n1={((\y4-\y3)/(\y2-\y1))} in 
    ($(A)-\n1*(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)$)
    --
    ($(B)+\n1*(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)$);
    \draw[name intersections={of=bbox and line},fill=blue] 
    (intersection-1) node[plotmark]{} -- (intersection-2) node[plotmark]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [plotmark/.style = {%
    solid,
    fill=red,
    circle,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    minimum size = 4pt}]

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-{30},local bounding box=a]
    \draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,0) rectangle ++(2,2) (0,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (4,-2) rectangle ++(2,2) (2,-4) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,-4);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \node[plotmark] at (A){};
    \node[plotmark] at (B){};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[fill=gray,name path global=bbox] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
    (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \path[overlay,name path=line] let \p1=(A),\p2=(B),\p3=(a.south),\p4=(a.north),\n1={((\y4-\y3)/(\y2-\y1))} in 
    ($(A)-\n1*(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)$)
    --
    ($(B)+\n1*(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)$);
    \draw[name intersections={of=bbox and line},fill=blue] 
    (intersection-1) circle (2pt) -- (intersection-2) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways, one of them. The filled area and the extra lines to the bounding box are drawn on the background layer with clipping.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  plotmark/.style = {%
    solid,
    fill=red,
    circle,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=4pt,
  },
]
  \begin{scope}[rotate=-30,local bounding box=bb]
    \draw
      (2, 4)
      -- (2, -2) coordinate (b)
      -- (4, -2) coordinate (c)
      -- (4, 4) coordinate (f)
      -- (0, 4) coordinate (g)
      -- (0, 0) coordinate (a)
      -- (6, 0) coordinate (d)
      -- (6, 2) coordinate (e)
      -- (0, 2)
    ;
    \coordinate (A) at (2, -2);
    \coordinate (B) at (2, 4);
    \node[plotmark] at (A){};
    \node[plotmark] at (B){};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \clip
      (bb.south west) rectangle (bb.north east)
      {[rotate=-30]
        (a) -| (b) -- (c) |- (d) -- (e) -| (f) -- (g) |- cycle
      }
    ;
    \fill[lightgray]
      (bb.south west) rectangle (bb.north east)
    ;
    \draw[rotate=-30]
      (A) -- ++(0, -2)
      (B) -- ++(0, 2)
    ;
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \draw (bb.south west) rectangle (bb.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]